# Any way to create pandas dataframe by parsing/splitting list of urls?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create pandas dataframe from list of urls where I want to split each url by hierarchy and create new columns for it. More specifically, I want to break up url by domain, protocol, query, fragment, paths. I think it's doable by using pandas, and I learned this solution but didn't get expected one.

**example data snippet**

Here is example data snippet in [csv file](https://jmp.sh/v/5GoTZ8g3CjeEluLgDLtU) and here is my attempt to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('example data snippet.csv')
df['protocol'],df['domain'],df['path'],df['query'],df['fragment'] = zip(*df['url'].map(urlparse.urlsplit))
```

above attempt wasn't successful because it's ouput doesn't meet with my expectation, so I am wondering is there better way to make this happen with `pandas`. Can anyone point me out how to make this work? Anyway to get this done easily? Any idea?

**desired output**

I want to split url and create new column for each component, the columns of my final pandas dataframe would be like this:

```
df.columns=['id', 'title', 'news source', 'topic', 'news category']
```

for example, in this url, I could say:

```
'variety.com/2017/biz/news/tax-march-donald-trump-protest-1202031487/'
'variety.com/2018/film/news/list-2018-oscar-nominations-1202668757/

news source =['variety.com','variety.com']
topic = ['tax-march-donald-trump-protest','list-2018-oscar-nominations']
new category = ['biz', 'film']
```

how can I do this kind of parsing for given urls list and add them into new column in pandas dataframe? anyway to get this done? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how many do you have?

I think I would go 1 by 1 because you're ignoring a random amount of stuff and you'll need to write rules for what to ignore.

if you use url.split("/") you'll get a list, but then you need to remove what you don't need to keep what you want.

once you have what you want, it will be in a nice shape where you can put it into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

urls = ['variety.com/2017/biz/news/tax-march-donald-trump-protest-1202031487/',
        'variety.com/2018/film/news/list-2018-oscar-nominations-1202668757/']

cols = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
make_me = []
for url in urls:
    lst = url.split("/")
    # your business rules go here
    make_me.append([x for x in lst if not x.isdigit() and not x == ""])

df = pd.DataFrame(make_me, columns=cols)
df


    c1          c2    c3    c4
0   variety.com biz   news  tax-march-donald-trump-protest-1202031487
1   variety.com film  news  list-2018-oscar-nominations-1202668757
```

Then you could reference each column as you like:

```
df.c1

>
0    variety.com
1    variety.com
Name: c1, dtype: object
```

and still have it all together and indexed. I think the rules might get tough and you might need to make them domain specific.

Comment: thanks for your solution. How can I make bit modification on `c4` column as `tax-march-donald-trump-protest` instead of `tax-march-donald-trump-protest-1202031487`? Thank you

Comment: again, split it on "-" and get rid of the last one, but that might only work for variety.com

Comment: thanks, is that doable to keep text only for `c4`? could you point me out how to do?

Comment: check out the string function isdigit() [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: I tried like this: `for i in df.c4:
    lst=i.split("-")
    res.append([''.join(x) for x in lst if not x.isdigit()])` but somehow digit in the middle was gone also, I just want to get rid of digit on text tail. Any better idea? Thank you

Comment: you could drop just the last one, drop if length = 10, etc. you need to play with the rules to get what you want.